# EMMS and LibreFM: How do I tell LibreFM to love or ban tracks?

Tags: emms, music-player

When I play something through LibreFM's web client, I can ask it to love or ban certain tracks. How do I do this in EMMS configured to play music from LibreFM?

Comment: I would ask at emms-help {at} gnu {dot} org... It seems like this would be easily built in if it is not already.